# При нажатии блока скрыть другие блоки

Tags: jquery, html

Друзья, не могу додумать как решить задачу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть такие блоки:

```
<span class="block">Содержимое</span>
<span class="block">Содержимое</span>
<span class="block">Содержимое</span>
<span class="block">Содержимое</span>
```

При нажатии одного из этих .block'ов нужно дать остальным .block'ам значение opacity, и показать блок:

```
<div id="block2" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="close">Закрыть</a>
    Содержимое
</div>
```

И внутри #block2 есть ссылка, при нажатии которой #block2 прячется и со всех .block'ов снимаем значение opacity.

Помогите пожалуйста! Спасибо.

Comment: А сколько блоков планиурется максимум? И как они выводятся? Посредством PHP, или заранее прописываются в html-коде?

Comment: @intro94, максимум 15 блоков, все заранее прописываются

Comment: при клике фильтруйте .block используя .not(this) - это будут остальные блоки. задавайте им opacity.

Comment: Блин. Это уже "веселее". Можно каждому блоку заранее присваивать `id="block_1"`, `id="block_2"` и тд. дальше понадобится три функции.

    function open(block){
        $('#'+block).show();
        closeOther(block);
    }
    function close(block){
        $('#'+block).hide();
    }
    function closeOther(block){
        var b = 1;
        while($('div').is('#block_'+b)){
            if(block != 'block_'+b)
                close('block_'+b);
            b++;
        }
    }

Если не заработает - пишите, буду думать. Если не понятно - объясню завтра утром. Спать уже хочу. :)

Comment: Ах да. В каждом блоке заранее вписывайте ссылку с закрытием. В ссылке на событие делайте `onclick="close('block_1');"`. Для открытия на каждый блок событие `onclick="open('block_1')"`. Не забывайте, у каждого блока свой номер, после подчёркивания.

Comment: @Maqsood видимо мне давно пора спать. Сейчас сравнил ваш код со своим - у меня, видимо, получилось горе от ума. XD
Совсем крыша поехала. действительно использование `.not()` облегчит работу. :)

Comment: @Maqsood, вам @eicto уже дал ответ в комментарии выше. Но чтобы хоть как-то разбавить "полет мыслей" у @intro94, держите [такой пример][1]. Правда, вы не указали: в единственном числе у вас блок **id="block2"** или нет, а если нет, то как связаны элементы с "Содержимым" с этими блоками и т.д., но думаю, что с этим уже разберетесь.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7SxM9/1/

Comment: посмотрел на решение @Deonis, мне кажется вебмастера 90х душу бы продали, чтобы так легко клепать интерфейсы.

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо, вы помогли.  
@intro94, @Deonis, благодарю за внимание! Было познавательно. :)